# MSRS folder present when Reporting Service is installed?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I know the answer to this, but i would like to confirm with you gurus out there :)

so, we have a client, and he said he has installed Reporting Service. However, I coudln't find any MSRS folder on his drive.

Usually, when a reporting service is installed properly, there should be a folder called MSRS$SOMETHING on the drive, correct?

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: A folder - yes, but that's not the naming convention I remember for v2005.  Also depends on what drive it was installed to.

Answer (score 0):

The default is C:\Programs Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.X\Reporting Services.  The "x" refers to the instance number, which is a sequential number assigned to the instance during install.  You can find the instance number (and directory) by either looking at the virtual directory properties in INETMGR or connect to the instance using the SQL Server Reporting Services Configuration tool from the program group.